# server startup issue with spring integration with integration-graph usage

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

HI I am having a weird issue with my spring batch jobexecution listner which I have added as a gateway as below

```
    @MessagingGateway(name="jobListenerGateway")
public interface JobStatusListener extends JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "jobRequests")
void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution);

@Override
@Gateway(requestChannel = "jobRequests")
void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution);
```

}

the exception which comes is as below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer$NodeFactory.gatewayNode(IntegrationGraphServer.java:281)
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer$NodeFactory.access$300(IntegrationGraphServer.java:266)
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.gateways(IntegrationGraphServer.java:187)
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.buildGraph(IntegrationGraphServer.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:104)
at org.springframework.integration.support.management.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:57)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
```

This happens as the integration graph code is not able to determine the request channel for this gateway , when as a workaround I introduce the `defaultRequestChannel` things works fine .

I have also observed the following does not happen with my other gateways only with this one where I am extending another interface .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug; in any case, we should never throw an NPE; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).